# How to split an object to an array

Tags: javascript

I want to split the object to be an array when the child value is an array. The new array length is the longest object child value length.（the longest length is three in the example）

Example:

```
// source
const data = {
  key1: 'key1',
  key2: ['key2-1', 'key2-2'],
  key3: ['key3-1', 'key3-2', 'key3-3'],
};

// expect to be:
const result = [
  { key1: 'key1', key2: 'key2-1', key3: 'key3-1' },
  { key2: 'key2-2', key3: 'key3-2' },
  { key3: 'key3-3' },
];

// my low code
const transform = (data) => {
  const maxLen = Object.values(data).reduce((max, value) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      if (value.length > max) {
        return value.length;
      }
    }
    return max;
  }, 0);
  const newArray = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < maxLen; index++) {
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (!newArray[index]) {
        newArray[index] = {};
      }
      if (Array.isArray(value) && value[index]) {
        newArray[index][key] = value[index];
      } else if (index === 0) {
        newArray[index][key] = value;
      }
    });
  }
  return newArray;
};
```

but my code is very low.have you a nice answer?

Comment: What's the logic for splitting? What did you try?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. We're a site that helps people on one part with code they've attempted but are having issues with. But you must _add that code to the question_.

Comment: Welcome to SO, btw. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: sry.I added a description of the problem. @Andy

Comment: can you help me? @Andy

Comment: Are the values inside the original arrays as `['key2-1', 'key2-2']` and `['key3-1', 'key3-2', 'key3-3']` always sorted?

Comment: it will always sorted.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the result:

```js
function toArray(data) {
  return Object.values(data).reduce((acc, currValue) => {
    Array.isArray(currValue)
      ? // e.g., ['key2-1', 'key2-3']
        currValue.forEach(v => addValues(acc, v))
      : // e.g., 'key1'
        addValues(acc, currValue)
    return acc
  }, [])

  function addValues(acc, value) {
    /*
      Split 'key2-1' into 'key2' and '1'
      Then assign 'key' = 'key2', 'index' = '1'
    */
    let [key, index] = value.split('-')

    /*
      The 'index' value is used to determine which object 
      the 'key' and 'value' will be stored in.

      Since array element indexes start from 0 and the numbering of keys 
      in the provided data object start from 1 the 'index' needs to be
      converted from string to number to substract 1 from it.

      The ' || 1'  part is becuase for the first value 'key1'.split('-') 
      will result in only ['key1'] so in the assignment:

        let [key, index] = ['key1']

      index will be undefined and it will be set to 0 :

        index = (Number(undefined) || 1) - 1
        index = (NaN || 1) - 1
        index = (1) - 1
        index = 0

    */
    index = (Number(index) || 1) - 1

    if (!acc[index]) {
      acc[index] = {}
    }
    acc[index][key] = value
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
const data = {
  key1: 'key1',
  key2: ['key2-1', 'key2-2'],
  key3: ['key3-1', 'key3-2', 'key3-3'],
}

function toArray(data) {
  return Object.values(data).reduce((acc, currValue) => {
    Array.isArray(currValue)
      ? currValue.forEach(v => addValues(acc, v))
      : addValues(acc, currValue)
    return acc
  }, [])

  function addValues(acc, value) {
    let [key, index] = value.split('-')
    index = (Number(index) || 1) - 1
    if (!acc[index]) acc[index] = {}
    acc[index][key] = value
  }
}

const result = toArray(data)
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```

---

References:

- `Object.values(data).reduce((acc, currValue) => { ... }, [])`:

  - [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
  - [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- `Array.isArray(currValue) ? currValue.forEach(v => ... ) : ...`:

  - [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)
  - [Conditional (ternary `?:`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
  - [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- `let [key, index] = value.split('-')`:

  - [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
  - [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- `index = (Number(index) || 1) - 1`:

  - [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number)
  - [Logical OR (`||`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Answer (score -2):

You can format it like so.

```
const data = { key1: 'key1', key2: ['key2-1', 'key2-2'] };

// [{"key1":"key1"},{"key2":"key2-1"},{"key2":"key2-2"}]
const res = Object.keys( data ).reduce( ( p, key ) => {
    if (typeof data[key] === 'string') {
        return p.concat( { [key]: key } )
    } else {
        return p.concat( Object.values( data[key] ).map( value => ({ [key]: value }) ) )
    }
}, [] )
```

Comment: You should add some notes to explain what your code does, and maybe use a snippet (`[<>]` in the edit toolbar) to create a testable example.

Comment: thank very much.but it is not my answer. I expect to be `[{key1:'key1',key2:'key2-1'},{key2:'key2-2'}]`

Comment: I added a description of the problem